# Getting Torch to recognize GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, torch

How do you get Torch to recognize CUDA on your video card?

I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 1030 running under Ubuntu 18.04, and it claims to [support CUDA](https://videocardz.com/69486/nvidia-geforce-gt-1030-features-384-cuda-cores), yet when I first tested Torch with it by running:

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 .env
. .env/bin/activate
pip install torch
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
```

it returned False, along with the warning:

```
    The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 9010).
Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new
version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install
a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version
of the CUDA driver.
```

So I ran all system updates and used Ubuntu's proprietary driver installer to install the most recent Nvidia-435 driver for my card.

However, `torch.cuda.is_available()` still returns false, but now it doesn't give me any warning.

Have I mis-configured Torch or does my GPU just not support CUDA?

Comment: This isn't a CUDA support issue, your GPU supports CUDA. There are well described, standard ways to test a CUDA installation in the CUDA documentation you can try, but there is no CUDA programming question here, so I have removed the tag

Comment: @talonmies With all due respect, I find your comment puzzling. I'm trying to write a program that uses CUDA and am unable to, but that doesn't make it a CUDA programming question?

Comment: Torch isn't CUDA, it is a GPU accelerated framework than can use CUDA under the hood. You are not doing any CUDA programming in any recognizable way, and you problem has nothing to do with CUDA programming in any recognizable way. And, in reality, if your answer is "I forgot to reboot after installing a driver", you question is probably completely off-topic for [SO] anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I spoke too soon. I didn't reboot after switching over the driver, and apparently that broke nvidia-smi and some other things that loaded the CUDA driver. After the reboot, Torch now recognizes CUDA 10.1 support.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah I checked this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute) and the GT 1030 is not compatible.

Comment: It supports CUDA, but admittedly the 1030 is a low end card with only 2GB of memory so they don't advertise it much as its features are pretty limited.